# simplifying boolean expression in maxterm

Tags: boolean-algebra

Should I expand the equation to simplify? Π(1,4,5,6). It means $$ F = (A + B + C')(A' + B + C)(A' + B + C')(A' + B' + C) $$ I have expanded and found $$ = ( C' + AC + A'B)(A' + BC + B'C') $$ I haven't gone on.

Comment: try grouping $1,5$ and $4,6$ instead

Comment: great. I have solved but how can you determine? I can't understand

Comment: recall this : $(x+y)(x'+y) = y$

Answer (score 1):

F = (A+B+C′) (A′+B+C) (A′+B+C′) (A′+B′+C)

Rearrange. 
(A+B+C′) (A′+B+C′) (A′+B+C) (A′+B′+C)

Theorem 11a in attached source. (X + Y) • (X + Y') = X

(B + C') (A' + C)

Multiply out. T8b.

A'B + BC + A'C + C'C

T4a - X • X' = 0

A'B + BC + A'C - minimized

http://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm